# Cannot find table 0 error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cannot find table 0.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table
>   0.

The error part of the code is " `dsReport.Tables[0].Load(drReport);`"

And my code for generateReport is :

```
ReportViewer1.Visible = true;
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

var sqlConnection = new SQLConnectionStrings();
var conReport = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection.strConn);
var cmdReport = new SqlCommand();


SqlDataReader drReport;

DataSet dsReport = new DataSet();
//PerfLogDataSet();
conReport.Open();

cmdReport.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmdReport.Connection = conReport;
cmdReport.CommandText = baseQuery;
drReport = cmdReport.ExecuteReader();
dsReport.Tables[0].Load(drReport);
drReport.Close();
conReport.Close();

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report.rdlc";
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dsReport.Tables[0]));

string installTime;
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Convert.ToInt64(PerformanceLogController.deliveryTime.ToString()));

installTime = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s:{3:D3}ms",
                 t.Hours,
                 t.Minutes,
                 t.Seconds,
                 t.Milliseconds);

string UinstallTime;
TimeSpan tU = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Convert.ToInt64(PerformanceLogController.deliveryTimeU.ToString()));

UinstallTime = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s:{3:D3}ms",
                 tU.Hours,
                 tU.Minutes,
                 tU.Seconds,
                 tU.Milliseconds);

ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("testParam", installTime.ToString());
ReportParameter p2 = new ReportParameter("date", DateTime.Now.ToString());
ReportParameter p3 = new ReportParameter("filterSum", filter);
ReportParameter p4 = new ReportParameter("testParam1", UinstallTime.ToString());

this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { p1, p2, p3, p4 });
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: `dsReport` do not have any `Tables`. But you are going to retrieve it from `dsReport` data set.

Answer (score 1):

There are no tables in `dsReport`. `dsReport` is not null else you would have got object reference exception.

You should create an SQLDataAdapter and fill DataTable with it like this

```
mydataAdapter.Fill(dsReport);
```

More on [SQLDataAdapter.Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I've added the SqlDataAdapter and MultipleActiveResultSets=true and it throws me this error. "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."